# await promise before callback in async.each

Tags: javascript, callback, async-await, es6-promise, async.js

```
router.post('/runCommand', async function(req, res){
  let results = [];
  async.each(req.body.requests, async function(request, callback){
    const data = await connect(request.command)
    await results.push(data);
    await callback(null);
  }, function(err){
    if (!err) {
      res.send(202, results)
    }
  })
})
```

Res.send is never taking place and callback seems to happen before connect is finished running. Connect is succesfully returning a promise because this

```
router.get('/topics', async function(req, res) {
  console.log('in get');
  const data = await connect(req.body.command);
  await res.send(data);
});
```

works fine. But including the async.each to run multiple commands seems broken. I know this is an issue with how I'm calling async.each callback function but research hasn't availed how I should be calling it. Is it possible to use a `.then()` after awaiting a promise?

```
function connect(command){
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
  let host = {
        server: {
          host: "host",
          port: "port",
          userName: "user",
          password: config.Devpassword
        },
        commands: [ command ]
      };
  var SSH2Shell = require ('ssh2shell'),
  //Create a new instance passing in the host object
  SSH = new SSH2Shell(host),
  //Use a callback function to process the full session text
  callback = function(sessionText){
    console.log(sessionText)
    resolve(sessionText);
  }
  SSH.connect(callback);
  })
};
```

Comment: Is your callback to `async.each()` ever being called? If so, what was the reported error? There's not enough information here to determine where you're going wrong. Are you sure the `req.body` of your POST request will be formatted like `{ requests: [ { command: ... }, ...] }`?

Comment: I can tell by console logs in the connect function that it is taking place for each command in the req. and yes that is the proper format. The issue I'm having is with when callback is being run. I isn't awaiting connect to finish running. so async.each goes through every command in the req before the results array is properly defined. Although I'm not sure why res.send never takes place. I assumed it would just send and array of unfulfilled promises but is actually never sending at all

Comment: Please provide the source for `connect()` by [edit]ing your answer. It seems like the problem is there.

Comment: And you get the `console.log(sessionText)` for every `request` in `req.body.requests`?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I added the source for `connect()` though I dont believ the issue is there. It returns a promise fine. When I only run a single command with the other function it properly awaits it to complete before res.sending the session text. I think the issue is with how i call callback() from async.each

Comment: yes, I tried passing 3 commands down and the console log happened for all 3

Comment: Try `callback()` instead of `callback(null)`. I'd be surprised if that works but that's the only thing that seems possible to make a difference here. You're misusing `await` in several places, but that doesn't affect what should happen.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts weirdly enough removing null at least made it so that res.send was called. But it only sent an empty array instead of an array of the sessionTexts. So `callback()` is definitely running before connect is finished. Is it possible to reformat connect to `const data = await connect().then( callback() )`

Comment: Are you sure the source you've posted for `router.post()` is what you're actually using? I don't mean to sound like I'm asking an obvious question; I'm asking because it's common for askers to remove code in posted snippets for brevity or proprietary reasons, and sometimes these removals cause the minimal example to behave differently.

Comment: And no, your suggested change would not work for multiple reasons.

Comment: Yes I double checked. It's identical, even down to function and variable names

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out this issue. It seems very bizarre to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could continue to sink more time into getting `async.each()` to work, I recommend just dropping it and going exclusively with the `async` / `await` syntax which simplifies your code a lot:

```
router.post('/runCommand', async function (req, res) {
  try {
    const results = await Promise.all(
      req.body.requests.map(({ command }) => connect(command))
    );

    res.send(202, results);
  } catch ({ message, stack }) {
    res.send(500, { error: message, stack });
  }
})
```

Looking at the `ssh2shell` documentation, I think your `connect` function could be improved as well for better readability and error handling:

```
const SSH2Shell = require('ssh2shell');

function connect (command) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const host = {
      server: {
        host: 'host',
        port: 'port',
        userName: 'user',
        password: config.Devpassword
      },
      commands: [command]
    };
    //Create a new instance passing in the host object
    const SSH = new SSH2Shell(host);

    SSH.on('error', reject);
    SSH.connect(resolve);
  });
}
```

Please feel free to comment if this still doesn't work for you.

Comment: thanks! you were 100% right about simplifying. I'll definitely use this but might look into async.each when I have more time.